# VSTS Build not including all dll's in artifact

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to build a dot-net web application in Azure DevOps using the agents/tasks below

> UseNuget, Nuget Restore, Visual Studio Build, Publish Build Artifact

[image: msbuild]

The Artifacts generated contain the dll's within the bin folder and some aspx pages.

[image: Artifact structure]

However it does not generate two folders inside the Bin folder named Release and Rosely which contain more dll's.

[image: Missing]

Can someone please suggest what i am doing wrong.

Comment: What parameters are you providing to MSBuild? What version of ASP .NET does your application use?

Comment: @DanielMann Question updated .net framework is 4.6.1

Comment: Ever figure this out?  I have only 1 file in my bin directory now after I upgraded one of our tools and switched over to Visual Studio 2019 (from 15)